# TextView inside layout with fixed height cutting off

Tags: android, label, textview

I have a calendar view with events inside a table. An event is created with a LinearLayout and a textview inside:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//My label
TextView label = new TextView(context);
label.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
label.setPadding(4, 0, 0, 10);
label.setText(text);

ll.addView(label, layoutParams);
```

When I add my LinearLayout to the calendar view, I got this:

[image]

My label is cutted off because of the linearlayout height. I dont want to change the height of my event. So I have set the property ellipsize with TruncateAt.END in my label in order to avoid this issue, but the problem persists. How can I have my label truncated at the end with (...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `setIncludeFontPadding()` to your `TextView`...this will remove all default padding from `TextView`.

```
label.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

One more thing, you have added `ellipsize` to your `TextView` but you didn't specify the length of the `TextView` after which the `ellipsize` should take effect. You can set that condition using any one of the following...

```
label.setSingleLine(true);
```

or

```
label.setMaxLines(2); //here maximum line 2
```

Comment: The problem is that the height of the LinearLayout is variable, so the number of lines too. But I can calculate the number of lines from the height of the layout. Thanks!